# time reminder application C#

Tags: c#, timer, alarm

I am trying to make an application in C# - visual studio 2010. This application is something like a reminder. You put the note into text box and use `DateTimePicker` to select when you need to be reminded of things. 
Problem is that I don't know how to do this.

I have selected date and time from DatetimePicker:

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
```

Now I need to compare time from datetimePicker with current date and time and if the value is the same show a message button with some text.

I am not sure if I may use timer and how to compare these values? Something like this :-)

```
string timese = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
string theDay = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (theDay == theDay2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show ("Reminder");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please help me find where is the problem in my code? `
     private DateTime theDay; 
     private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
     DateTime theDay = dateTimePicker1.Value;
     pictureBox3.Visible = true;
     MessageBox.Show("data saved");
     timer1.Enabled = true;
    } 
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
     if (DateTime.Now.CompareTo(theDay) > 0 ) // checks if now is      after theDay
     {
     theDay = DateTime.MaxValue;
     timer1.Enabled = false;
     MessageBox.Show ("Reminder")`

Answer (score 2):

Dont use strings first of all:

```
DateTime theDay = dateTimePicker1.Value;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DateTime.Now.CompareTo(theDay) > 0 ) // checks if now is after theDay
    {
        theDay = DateTime.MaxValue;
        // makes sure there wont be multiple MessageBox due to event queuing
        // you could also just stop the timer here
        MessageBox.Show ("Reminder");
    }
}
```

exact matches (==) for date is not recommended, because the timer might jump over the exact time and it will never be true.

Edit: my comparission was the wrong way, it should be correct now

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be exactly what I need. But I have one question, maybe very stupid still ..

When I use this:

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DateTime theDay = dateTimePicker1.Value;}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DateTime.Now.CompareTo(theDay) > 0 )
    {
        theDay = DateTime.MaxValue;
        MessageBox.Show ("Reminder");
}

It show error: The name 'theDay' does not exist in the current context. I supposte I have to define theDay somewhere else ... Could please explain me where and how? In public partial class?

Answer (score 0):

You can just compare:

```
if(dateTimePicker1.Value==DateTime.Now)
```

Both are datetime.

But there is one problem with above code. It compares time with milliseconds, Probably never it will be same. So you can change your code to something like

```
if(dateTimePicker1.Value-DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds<2)
```

(DateTime1 - DateTime2) is timespan more abote this class is on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.timespan.totalseconds.aspx)

Comment: the timer would have to tick in the exact same millisecond for that to work. really bad solution